Constructible sheaves on $\mathbb{C}^n$
Let $X=\mathbb{C}^n$ with coordinates $z_1,\ldots, z_n$, $Z$ the hyperplane $z_1=0$, and $U=X\setminus Z.$ Endow $X$, $Z$ and $U$ with the normal crossings stratification. We have the closed embedding $i: Z\to X$, the open embedding $j: U\to X$ and the trivial fibration $p: U\to Z$ with fiber $\mathbb{C}^\times$.
Let $F$, an object of the bounded derived category of sheaves $D^b(Sh(U))$, be weakly constructible on $U$, i.e. an object such that its cohomology sheaves restrict to local systems on all strata, possibly local systems of infinite rank. I am interested in $p_* F$ and $i^*j_*F$.
I am almost sure that these two objects are the same. Now, describing them explicitly in general might be difficult, so I will be satisfied with computing their fibers at the points of $Z$. For a point $z\in Z$, is it true that $(p_* F)_z\cong R\Gamma(p^{-1}(z), F|_{p^{-1}(z)})$? More generally, does base change hold for the morphism $p$ and constructible complexes?
This looks plausible, since base change does hold for locally trivial fibrations $p: U\to Z$ and local systems (or complexes with locally constant cohomology) on $U$. The obvious way to generalize to constructible sheaves is to ask for the stratification of $U$ to be such that the induced stratification on the fibers of $p$ is trivial (or even start with the trivial fibrations $\mathrm{pr}: Z\times Y\to Z$), but I was unable to prove the base change theorem in this setting or find a reference.

Take a look at Lemma B.2.2 (pg 517) of "Perverse Sheaves and Applications to Representation Theory" by Pramod Achar. I think the statement you want is a special case of that where $k=1$ and $I={1}$ (see beginning of Section B.2 on pg 515 for the notation and setup). Also, $F$ should be an object in $D^b(Sh(U))$ (not $D^b(Sh(X)))$ to make sense of $j_*F, p_*F$-in this case, $F$ is just a bounded complex of sheaves with cohomology sheaves being local systems (since U is a stratum).

@I'mRepresentable you are right about switching $X$ to $U$, thank you. I am aware of this section of Achar's book. In the lemma, $U$ is the open stratum, but in my case, $U$ is the complement of a hyperplane and has lots of strata.
